# Не удается сохранить данные полученные по API запросу в переменную для использования в следующем API запросе)

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Необходимо получить export_id из 1 запроса, положить значение в переменную и использовать его в следующем запросе.
В конечном результате наткнулся на следующую ошибку:

> export_id = result['info']['export_id'] TypeError: list indices must
> be integers or slices, not str

```
import requests
import time
import schedule
import datetime as DT


account_name = "100"
today_str = DT.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

#Данные для запроса Export_ID
BASE_URL_EXPORT_ID = f"https://{account_name}.getcourse.ru/pl/api/account/users"
params_export_id = {'key' : '5D6JZ',
                    'created_at[from]' : today_str,
                    'created_at[to]': today_str}

#Данные для получение информации
BASE_URL_DATA = f"https://{account_name}.getcourse.ru/pl/api/account/exports/"
export_id = 0
params_data = {'export_id' : export_id,
               'key' : '5D6JZ'}
    
def run():
    global export_id
    print('Получаем Export_id')
    today_str = DT.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    #получаем export_id 
    response = requests.get(BASE_URL_EXPORT_ID, params=params_export_id)
    result = response.json()
    #пытаюсь сохранить данные для 2 части запроса :)
    export_id = result['info']['export_id']

    #получаю сами данные
    response1 = requests.get(BASE_URL_DATA, params=params_data)
    result1 = response1.json()
    print (result1)

schedule.every().day.at("15:40").do(run)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
#проверяю записались ли данные в переменную    
print (export_id)
```

Comment: В `result` у вас какие данные лежат? Не массив ли там случаем вместо объекта?

Comment: @VenZell, Вот такие:
{'success': True, 'info': {'export_id': 3770242}, 'error_message': '', 'error': False}

Comment: @Sergei Malanin, а как правильно? Выше в комментарии я подкрепил результат запроса по верным авторизационным данным. Мне необходимо сохранить в переменную информацию ключа 'export_id'. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Результат вашего запроса.

```py
result = response.json()
result 
Out[4]: 
{'success': False,
 'info': [],
 'error_message': 'Неавторизованное API-обращение',
 'error': True,
 'error_code': 901}
```

Соответствено `result['info']` это список, а вы с ним как с диктом обращаетесь. И там что то с авторизацией у вас не так.

Comment: Обращайтесь к участникам форума "на вы", пожалуйста.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, поправил.